# Mailgun - remove "on behalf of" when sending mail to Outlook user

Tags: email, outlook, mailgun

I'm trying to get rid of the "on behalf of" which appear in our mails when **Outlook users** receive those mails (Gmail is OK).

I've set all the necessary settings of Mailgun - including SPF & DKIM of my domain. All marked green as successful.

Although, outlook users are still getting the annoying "on behalf of" instead of sender (name@domain.com), and as a consequence our mails marked as spam which is extremely problematic.

I'm not sure if this is Mailgun problem - as much as I know it isn't. After looking in google I failed to find something positive - or even Microsoft statement that its impossible to do that.

Hope you've got a solution for that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the From and Sender MIME headers are different.